# After a git rebase master mistakenly executed git pull instead of git push origin/your_branch -f

Tags: git, github, version-control, rebase, git-rebase

Probably due to lack of sleep instead of executing a force push after a `git rebase master` I've executed a `git pull`. Now my pull request is messed up including all the commits from master.
Any suggestion to revert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reflog` has come to the rescue for me on multiple occasions.

This reference log records updates to your local repository/branches/references.

So if you find the head commit of the desired branch directly before the pull in this case, you can reset your current branch to that reference.  For example to reset to `HEAD@{2}`

`git reset --hard HEAD@{2}`

Note: **be absolutely sure** about your action before using `--hard`

[Git reflog documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

Comment: thanks, my branch is fixed! Used reflog to find the last good commit, reset the branch to that reference and concluded with a forced push.

Answer (score 0):

Running `git pull` is just a fetch followed by a merge of the upstream branch.  Assuming the merge succeeded and you still have this branch checked out, something like this should fix it:

```
$ git reset @^1
```

That resets the branch to the first parent which should be the rebased branch (the second parent being the head of the old upstream version of the branch.)  You can verify before doing the reset:

```
$ git log --graph @^1
```

or

```
$ gitk @^1
```

If those look sane, then the reset should do it.  It will not touch the files in your work tree so you can see if this resulted in any surprising changes.  I suspect there will be none as the merge was probably a no-op as far as the code is concerned (again, assuming it succeeded.)